# Why is $\int f(x) dx = \int_0^1 |f\ge t|dt$, where $0\le f\le 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Why is $$\int f(x) dx = \int_0^1 |f\ge t|dt$$
> true? Apparently, it comes from **Fubini's theorem** - which allows us to write the integral of $f$ as the integral of the length of its level set? Also note that $\sup f = 1$, $f \ge 0$ and $f$ is integrable.

Could someone help me understand where this comes from, and what's going on? Intuition would be helpful too.

Given a function $f$, I understand that $\{x:f(x) = t\}$ is one of its level sets. Is that right? I don't see how this relates with the above equality though.

**Reference:** [Pg. 31, Notes](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf).

Comment: Not true as written; you must assume that $f$ is bounded by $1$.

Comment: @uniquesolution also you must assume that $f$ is non-negative

Comment: @Masacroso  True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the [layer-cake representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation) of the integral. In this case, I assume that $0 \le f(x) \le 1$ for all $x$. Then you can write $$\lvert \{ f \ge t \} \rvert = \int_{\{f \ge t\}} 1  \, dx = \int \mathbb I_{\{f \ge t\}}(x) dx,$$ where $\mathbb I_{\{f\ge t\}}$ is the indicator function of the set $\{ x: f(x) \ge t\}$. Thus $$\int_0^1 \lvert \{ f \ge t \} \rvert dt = \int^1_0 \int \mathbb I_{\{f \ge t\}} (x) dx dt = \int\int^1_0\mathbb I_{\{f \ge t\}} (x) dt dx,$$ where the last step follows from Fubini's theorem. Now notice that $$\mathbb I_{\{ f \ge t\}} (x) = \left \{ \begin{matrix} 1, & t \le f(x), \\ 0, & t > f(x). \end{matrix}\right.$$ Thus the inner integral simplifies and we get $$\int_0^1 \lvert \{ f \ge t \} \rvert dt = \int \int^{f(x)}_0 dt dx = \int f(x) dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'd say is that this clearly is not always the case - in order to answer this you need to know that $f$ is non-negative and $\sup f = 1$, as is given in the notes you linked. As for your identity, let me work from right to left. We have
$$|f \geq t| = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \chi_{\{f(x) \geq t\}},$$
which is just a basic property of the Lebesgue measure - the 'length' of the set is the integral of its characteristic function w.r.t the Lebesgue measure. Now we substitute this in to your original identity and apply Fubini to exchange the order of integration to obtain
$$\int_{0}^{1}|f \geq t| d t = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{0}^{1} \chi_{\{f(x) \geq t\}} dt dx.$$
Here, in the integral in the middle $x$ is fixed and t varies. So on $0 \leq t \leq f(x)$ the characteristic function will equal $1$, and on $f(x) \leq t \leq 1$ it will equal $0$, where here we're using the fact $f$ takes values in $[0,1]$. Thus,
$$\int_0^1 \chi_{\{f(x) \geq t\}} dt = f(x),$$
and we obtain the identity you're after. I think when they say 'level sets' in your reference, they're referring to the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R^n} \; | \; f(x) \geq t\}$ which I suppose ought to be called a superlevel set.